# How to access settings from `.env` inside the `index.php`

Tags: laravel, phpdotenv

I’m creating a deployment configuration for Laravel project.
On my hosting `public/` folder must be moved to another place.
Obviously, since that, I need to change path to the `autoload.php` and `app.php` in `index.php`.

However, I’d like to add and use a parameter which would tell where these files reside. Something like this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../' . env('DEP_EXT_FOLDER') . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

I think, the most proper place for such a parameter is .env file.
However, I’ve got an error:

```
Call to undefined function env()
```

Comment: @lagbox , yes, I see, of course, you are right

Comment: that `env` function comes from one of the libraries that the autoloader is responsible for loading ... i would look at a different method  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `env()` function before loading the autoloader.

if you absolutely want to use your .env file, you will have to use native php preg_match() for finding your key and using the value after that :)